# Is there a way to allow chrome use your camera and microphone for selenium script? I don't want to pass fake stream

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, camera, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am aware of ChromeOptions and passing fake media stream
options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");

But I don't want to pass fake media. I want to use my laptop's camera

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("media.default_video_capture_Device", "\\\\?\\root#media#0002#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\\global");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

Camera code could be obtained from settings window (inspect with dev tools) or from preferences file in Chrome directory.